# Included PHP file that references a file - location always changes

Tags: php, url, include

Bit hard to put this into words for the title. Basically, I have a PHP class that reads and writes data to a file in the file system. I need to access this data from several scripts so I created 1 central instance of the class that loads the data and tried to reference it by including the script whereever I need to access the data. The problem with this is that the path to the file that gets loaded and written to by the class is then relative to whichecer script is doing the including, rather than PHP file that the object is instantiated in.

What's the best way of handling this? I can't use an absolute URL as the system is to be deployed and so I don't know what the URL will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to use one of these solutions:

http://www.bitflop.com/document/95

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you know the location of the file you want to access relative to the php script you in:
You can be absolutely sure if you use the  **__*DIR*__** magic constant.

> require_once **__*DIR _*_**.'/known_location/file_required.php';

or for versions of php older than 5.3

> require_once dirname(**__*FILE _*_**).'/known_location/file_required.php';

Comment: I had problems adding the underscores to this answer. Just to be clear use double underscores before and after DIR and FILE

Answer (score 0):

yoursite.com/index.php?page=subdir

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'] || $_GET['page']==home){
$page = '/';
}elseif($_GET['page']=="subdir"){
$page = '../';
}
else{
// someone messed with the url
header('location: yoursite.com');
}

include $page . 'yourfile.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I wouldn't want to have a query string on every page